# how can I get more specific error reporting on magento customer import?

Tags: magento, import, importerror, magmi

I'm trying to import 80k customers into magento using the dataflow import method built into magento...it's really difficult to work with...

- It's really slow to import
- I need to break the 80k into files of 1k each to avoid the import process falling over
- When an import fails I get a cryptic error message of: there is an error with this 'field'
- Each import is slow

Does any one have a better solution to dealing with the above 4 issues? Or at least is Magento genius able to provide a getting row numbers to be reported along with fields that are causing errors so I can identify the failure more immediately and fix?

I'm sure I'm not the only one experiencing this issue so I'd be very grateful to hear the solutions other's have come across for this.

There's a great solution tackling this issue for products called Magmi, unfortunately seems to be a little bit of a blackhole when it comes to customers import/export...

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Customers in Magento is EAV Model

So Basically you need email / First Name / Last Name / Password / Customer Group / Store ID

You can right normal mysql queries that insert in

```
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
```

and get the Attribute ids from eav_attribute and do the queries with last_insert_id();

Comment: thanks Meabed, this is helpful albeit a little too far beyond what I'm familiar with to script. Not really sure how to write the mysql queries as I've not had to work with mysql before so a no-gaps example would be immensely helpful if there's no front end solution like magmi.

Answer (score 0):

add more time to the php execution time and add memory in the php.ini

[increase execution time and memory limit](http://www.teknobites.com/2007/04/27/how-to-edit-phpini-file-to-increase-memory-limit/)